# Gaming on Ubuntu - how and why?

Tags: virtualbox, wine, games, vmware

So I have Ubuntu 13.10 on my Dell Inspiron 1564 which has VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller, and I'm not a gamer, but I want to play that old Start Wars games (The Old Republic, Galactic Empire, Jedi Academy).

My question is - should I use Wine OR VMware OR VirtualBox ? and WHY ?

Comment: From what I've found on Google, your laptop has Intel GMA graphics. These predate the current Intel HD integrated graphics and are significantly worse. It's possible that some or all of the games will simply not work properly or well on your system, regardless of which OS you use.

Comment: Did you check to see if they are on Steam as you can play some STEAM games on it.

Answer (score 2):

Wine or CrossOver. You will loose SO MUCH performance with VMs.

Try:
    http://www.codeweavers.com/products/ (I am not affiliated with them)

or:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

If you're trying wine, you might also want to check [here](https://www.winehq.org/) to resolve winetrick dependency and specific wine versions working and others not issues.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say whether virtualization or Wine would function better, but I'd take a look at [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/). It's a one-stop shop for installing a lot of software via Wine, including several games (including KOTR and Jedi Academy, but Galactic Empire isn't listed). It removes the sometimes painful process of setting up Wine to work with an application i.e. installing dependencies.

Otherwise, bear in mind that to run Windows on a virtual machine, you'll need a licensed copy, and if you already have it installed in dual-boot I don't believe you are allowed to install it on a virtual drive as well.

Comment: I'd like to know if I'll be able to play the unlisted games + I'd like to get installation help.

Comment: You can download the .deb [here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html). Once you've downloaded it, just open the file and the Software Center should guide you through the rest. As for installing the games themselves, there's a menu on the application where you can choose a game and hit 'Install'. It will likely require the installation disc, so if you have a Steam copy you'll have to find another way.

For your other game(s), I can't be of much assistance, I don't actually know a whole lot about Wine.